# How to control functions in certain media queries in React using hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project in that I have a button, for that button I have written one onClick function now what I need is when I click the button it only needs to change background color only to mobile screen from min(0px) to max(576px) in this screen only the function change has to apply.

This is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const [color,setColor]=useState('red');
  const [textColor,setTextColor]=useState('white');

 const  changeBackGround =() =>{
    {setColor("black");setTextColor('red')}
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={{background:color,color:textColor}} onClick={changeBackGround} className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

If you have any questions please let me know. Thank you

Comment: did you try out some of the answers? Consider giving some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Have a state object that updates the the className on the button click. Update the className in the css media query.

```
        import React, { useState } from 'react';
        import './App.css';
        
        
        function App() {
          const [color,setColor]=useState('red');
          const [textColor,setTextColor]=useState('white');
          const [buttonClassName, setButtonClassName] = useState("");
        
         const  changeBackGround = () =>{
            setColor("black");
            setTextColor('red');
            setButtonClassName("btn-update");
          }
          return (
            <div className="App">
              <button 
                  style={{background:color,color:textColor}} 
                  onClick={changeBackGround} 
                  className={`btn btn-primary ${buttonClassName}`}>
              Click here
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        }
        
        export default App
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .btn-update {
    background-color: "green";
 }
}
```

Comment: how will your `changeBackGround` know that the screen size is less than 576px ?

Comment: It doesn't, that is taken care by css media query. But if you want to know the size of the screen in the `changeBackGround` function, query for body tag and get the size by looking for clientWidth

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state variable to update when the screen gets to a certain width. In a `useEffect()`, you can add a `eventListener` to the window that listens to the screen resizing. When the screen gets resized to a certain width, we update the state and use it to do conditional rendering in the `return`.

```js
const [show, setShow] = useState(false); // state value for showing / hiding

useEffect(() => {
  const handleResize = () => {
    window.innerWidth < 576 ? setShow(true) : setShow(false); // set hide / show
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize); // add event listener
}, []);

return ({
  show ? <h1>show</h1>: <h1>hide</h1>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways

1. check your `window.innerWidth` . But this will not work when you resize your window in the browser. To Test this what you can do is resize your browser window so the width is less than 576px and refresh your screen and click the button now .

```
    const  changeBackGround =() =>{
        if(window.innerWidth < 576){
           setColor("black");
           setTextColor('red')}
        } else {
          ...do something
        }
      }
```

2. Attach an event listener which listens for your resize event , now when you resize the window the `width` is maintained in state.

```
    function App() {
      const [deviceSize, changeDeviceSize] = useState(window.innerWidth);
      const [color, setColor] = useState('red');
      const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState('white');
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => changeDeviceSize(window.innerWidth);
    
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    
        // don't forget to remove the event listener on unmounting the component
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      }, []);
    
      const changeBackGround = () => {
        if (deviceSize < 576) {
          {
            setColor('black');
            setTextColor('red');
          }
        }
      };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <button
            style={{background: color, color: textColor}}
            onClick={changeBackGround}
            className="btn btn-primary"
          >
            Click here
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger things dynamically, use custom hooks to get window size (generic) and another custom hook to check if it's valid for mobile (can be kept in a separate hooks folder).

useWindowSize.js

```
// Hook from https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/
function useWindowSize() {
  // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
  // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
      // Set window width/height to state
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
      });
    }
    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();
    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount
  return windowSize;
}
```

useIsMobile.js

```
const MAX_SIZE_FOR = { mobile: 576 };

const useIsMobile = () => {
  const { width } = useWindowSize();
  return width < MAX_SIZE_FOR;
};
```

yourComponent.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useIsMobile } from './useIsMobile'
import "./App.css";


function App() {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState({ background: "red", textColor: "white" });
  const isMobile = useIsMobile();
  const changeBackGround = () => {
    if (isMobile) {
      setStyle({ ...style, background: "black", textColor: "red" });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={style} onClick={changeBackGround} className="btn btn-primary">
        Click here
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can even change the color on the fly via `useEffect`

```
const { width } = useWindowSize();
useEffect(changeBackGround, [width]);
```